# Concurrency error causing "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following function that takes a `BookForUpdateDto` and updates the `Book` entity based on the updated properties. When I try to update items inside of a ICollection of the `Book` it works all right when adding one item or when removing one item, but when calling these operations right after another (first one call where one item from the collection is removed, then one call where another item is added), I get an exception on `SaveChangesAsync()` telling me "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);".

This is my code:

```cs
    public async Task UpdateBookAsync(string email, BookForUpdateDto bookUpdateDto)
    {
        var user = await _userRepository.GetAsync(email, trackChanges: true);
        var book = user.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.BookId == bookUpdateDto.Guid);
        if (book == null)
        {
            const string message = "No book with this id exists";
            throw new CommonErrorException(404, message, 4);
        }
        await _bookRepository.LoadRelationShipsAsync(book);

        var dtoProperties = bookUpdateDto.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var dtoProperty in dtoProperties)
        {
            // Manually handle certain properties
            switch (dtoProperty.Name)
            {
                // ...
                case "Highlights":
                {
                    Collection<Highlight> newHighlights = new();
                    foreach(var highlightInDto in bookUpdateDto.Highlights)
                    {
                        newHighlights.Add(_mapper.Map<Highlight>(highlightInDto));
                    }

                    book.Highlights = newHighlights;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            
            // Update any other property via reflection
            var value = dtoProperty.GetValue(bookUpdateDto);
            SetPropertyOnBook(book, dtoProperty.Name, value);
        }

        await _bookRepository.SaveChangesAsync();  // <-- Error is thrown here
    }
```

Comment: Most probably you are invoking UpdateBookAsync in parallel or if sequentially, the start of the second invoke overlaps the execution of the first invoke of the method. What is happening is that the that the SaveChangesAsync is called after the execution of "user.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.BookId == bookUpdateDto.Guid);" during the second invoke of the method. The result is that when the second SaveChangesAsync is called, EF sees that the state of the database has already been changed and the new changes cannot be saved(optimistic lock mechanism)

Comment: I suspected something similar to this, but I'd have no idea how I would be supposed to solve this. Is there something I can do about this problem?

Comment: yes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations#resolving-concurrency-conflicts.

OR If you accept that latest changes are the correct ones, you can implement retry mechanism, when DbUpdateConcurrencyException  occurs. Easily  achievable with Polly library https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly

Comment: Thanks, I have read through the microsoft docs and all I want to do is simply accept the previous state and add my changes to it. Could I do that with Polly?

Comment: If You are the only user of the database, then a solution could be to eliminate "async and await", so an operation doesn't overlap with the previous one. But, for a serious resolution of this problem, You should manage the Optimistic Concurreny, adding a rowVersion column in every entity and enclosing save operations inside a try-catch block. In this case, a better approach, could be to update **book.Highlights** rows, not the collection inside book entity.

Comment: @AntoanElenkov couldn't I simply do something like this:

https://paste.myst.rs/sdj1enhy (Cant format the code in here for some reason)

Which would call the method again and thus cause the book to be reloaded?

Comment: Also, if You update **book.HighLights** rows (not the collection which will be updated automatically), when adding new rows, You don't need to manage Concurrency.

Comment: @FabioCaruso can you please elaborate that? I am not sure if I understand what you mean

Comment: @Creapermann, seems okay to me, but you can add another parameter to the method for number of retries in order to prevent stackoverflow exception(this is an extreme situation, which may never happen, but it is always good to be protected)

Answer (score 0):

If You add the new Highlights, updating directly **_bookRepository.Highlights** table (not books Collection), You can add every new row, without worry about Optimistic Concurrency. You can do:

```
 ...
case "Highlights":
{
   Collection<Highlight> newHighlights = new();
   foreach(var highlightInDto in bookUpdateDto.Highlights)
   {
        newHighlights.Add(_mapper.Map<Highlight>(highlightInDto));
   }

   foreach (Highlight hl in newHighlights)
   {
        hl.BookId = book.BookId;
        _bookRepository.Highlights.Add(hl);
   }    
   _bookRepository.SaveChanges();
   continue;
}
```

Comment: Ah, you mean like e.g. adding a _highlightRepository and using that, right?

Comment: Yes, because if You **add** You don't need to worry about Concurrency; if You **remove** (or better executeDelete()), You can enclose the operation inside try-catch and repeat it, verifying also if someone else removed it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with this approach. The main one is trying to replace the child collection references by creating a new collection:

```
foreach(var highlightInDto in bookUpdateDto.Highlights)
{
    newHighlights.Add(_mapper.Map<Highlight>(highlightInDto));
}

book.Highlights = newHighlights;
```

With singular references you replace items with instances tracked by the DbContext, with collections you need to add and remove references.

So for instance, if your book has a collection of Highlights and you want to replace these values with a new set, you need to determine which highlights need to be added, and which might need to be replaced. If Highlights are references to existing records in a table as opposed to unique children "owned" by each book, then you need to load those references to the highlights to be added from the DbContext and associate them with the book.

To address updating the Highlights on the book, assuming Highlights are references:

```
var updatedHighlightIds = bookUpdateDto.Highlights
    .Select(x => x.HighlightId);
var existingHighlightIds = book.Highlights
    .Select(x => x.HighlightId);
var highlightIdsToAdd = updatedHighlightIds
    .Except(existingHighlightIds)
    .ToList();
var highlightIdsToRemove = existingHighlightIds
    .Except(updatedHighlightIds)
    .ToList();

foreach(var highlightId in highlightIdsToRemove)
{
    book.Highlights.Remove(book.Highlights.First(x => x.HighlightId == highlightId));
}

if (highlightIdsToAdd.Any())
{
    var highlights = await _context.Highlights
        .Where(x => highlightIdsToAdd.Contains(x.HighlightId))
        .ToListAsync();
    foreach(var highlight in highlights)
    {
        book.Highlights.Add(highlight);
    }
}
```

If instead highlights are something to be created as new references, owned solely by each book, then you could use a similar approach, but instead of fetching the highlights from the DbContext, `new` up the highlights that need to be added. In these cases the matching of highlights might not be done based on Highlight ID but rather something that uniquely identifies them.

I do not recommend using per-entity Repository patterns such as the Generic Repository with EF. Patterns like this add no real value when working with EF and impose what can be significant limitations to what you can do. It isn't clear what this method does:

```
await _bookRepository.LoadRelationShipsAsync(book);
```

but I am assuming it will explicitly load the Highlights and other relation references for the given book.

Code like this:

```
var user = await _userRepository.GetAsync(email, trackChanges: true);
var book = user.Books.SingleOrDefault(book => book.BookId == bookUpdateDto.Guid);
```

is particularly wasteful, as you are loading a user, then lazy-loading all of the Books for that user. Alternatively, using the DbContext/DbSet and navigation properties, this could be replaced with just:

```
var book = await _context.Books
    .Include(x => x.Highlights)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.BookId == bookUpdateDto.Guid && x.User.Email == email);
```

This would fetch just the single book and it's highlights in one query hit. If you needed to include several relations you can append `.AsSplitQuery()` to address the possibility of a large Cartesian Product in the resulting single query.