# EF Core AsNoTracking on a table called with ThenInclude

Tags: entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I've been fighting with EF Core for the better part of a day now, and I can't seem to get it fixed.

I have a database model which has a lot of related tables, some in a 'cascade' system. This all works great in a EF Core scaffolded project, I haven't had to write a single SQL query (this is the first time I'm using EF Core).

Here is a simplified DB scheme of the problematic tables:

[image]

`HH_Dossiers` is my "main" table where all other tables are somehow related to. `HH_Betrokkenen` can have multiple records linked to the same `DossierID`, but they are all from a certain `Type` (defined in `HH_BetrokkeneTypes`). This last table should not be modified as it is a static list of possible types.

Using EF Core in my Blazor application as I was doing on other parts in the app suddenly I get an error

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'HH_BetrokkeneTypes' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value <> is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

I get this error when I want to insert a new `HH_Betrokkenen` record. The error is somewhat logical because yes, `BetrokkeneTypeID` can be used multiple times.

I find it a bit strange that EF can't handle this kind of linked tables, but that's another thing.

Now, what I have found is that disabling tracking (using `AsNoTracking`) on the `HH_BetrokkeneTypes` object/table should fix this. It's useless that it should be tracked anyway, because it won't change.

I 'build' my main `HH_Dossiers` object that is used throughout the app this way:

```
DossierObject = context.HH_Dossiers
.Include(dossier => dossier.Adres)
<other unrelated includes>
.Include(dossier => dossier.HH_Betrokkenen)
    .ThenInclude(betrok => betrok.BetrokkeneType)
.Include(dossier => dossier.HH_Betrokkenen)
    .ThenInclude(betrok => betrok.Adres)
.First(a => a.DossierID == DossierID);
```

So here's my main question: how do I disable tracking specifically on the `HH_BetrokkeneType` table? Just adding `AsNoTracking` in the code above isn't possible because it won't track anything, and I do need that.

I tried replacing the sequential includes with this:

```
IQueryable<HH_Betrokkenen> betrokkenen = ctx.HH_Betrokkenen.Where(x => x.DossierID == DossierID);
betrokkenen = betrokkenen.Include(x => x.BetrokkeneType).AsNoTracking();
betrokkenen = betrokkenen.Include(x => x.Adres);
DossierObject.HH_Betrokkenen = betrokkenen.ToList();
```

But that didn't work either, gave me the exact same problem.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.  You have to specify to EF what tables you want to update and what you don't.  Here is an example.

My main object is a `Request`.  I'm setting my `RequestType` to unchaged by 'attaching' it to the (`Request`) context.  This is a 1:1 relationship.  Then in the foreach loop I'm setting each of my `RequestStatus.StatusTypes` as 'attached'.  Each `Request` can have multiple status' and each `Status` has a `StatusType`.  I don't want to update the type.

```
try
{
    context.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Added;
    context.Attach(request.RequestType);

    foreach (var requestStatus in request.RequestStatuses)
    {
        context.ChangeTracker.TrackGraph(requestStatus, x => { x.Entry.State = EntityState.Added; });
        context.Attach(requestStatus.StatusTypes);
    }

    foreach (var entry in context.ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
        var entityName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
        var state = entry.State.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(state + " " + entityName);
    }
```

In your case, its you `HH_BetrokkeneTypes` that would be attached.

That second foreach will loopo through your context and tell you what status each object is in.  Its nice when you have a complex graph.

Answer (score 0):

There are likely a couple of issues you are encountering. The first thing is to ensure that when re-associating entities, you are always dealing with instances loaded from the same DbContext. I cannot tell from the limited code you have provided, but ensure that when loading new references to associate with an entity, that the same DbContext instance is used. A common issue I see is when people use things like Generic Repositories where each repository has a different DbContext instance where the replacement Betrokkenens are loaded by one DbContext and it tries associating them to a Dossier with Betrokkenes loaded and tracked by a different DbContext. This results in the error you are seeing, where an entity (or eagerly loaded child/reference) from one DbContext happens to already have another instance for the same row loaded in the target DbContext. Before attaching any entity to a DbContext, you should always check that DbContext's tracking cache to see if it is already tracking one. Wherever possible it is best to always just ensure you are using the same DbContext instance, and not detached references. (I.e. use `AsNoTracking` for read-only optimizations, not update scenarios)

The other significant issue is when it comes to navigation properties is you replace singular references, you do *not* replace collections.

When you do this:

```
DossierObject.HH_Betrokkenen = betrokkenen.ToList();
```

What you think might happen is telling EF to remove any existing Betrokken and replace them with the set you have loaded. What actually happens is you are telling EF, Associate all these new ones. This leads to unexpected issues. When updating collections you need to be deliberate, remove what items need to be removed and associate what items need to be added.

See my recent answer here ([Concurrency error causing "The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77104390/concurrency-error-causing-the-database-operation-was-expected-to-affect-1-rows/77116046#77116046)) for how to update child collections.